# tkinter askdirectory()

Tags: python, tkinter, taskdialog

File move based on last update. Using button 3 only, I am missing a slash at the end of the directory. This causes the path to merge with the text files I am trying to move:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python34/check2.py", line 30, in fileMove
    if os.stat(src).st_mtime > now - 1 * 86400:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Somewhere/filenametextfile'
```

```
import shutil, sys, time, os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
root = Tk()

def fileMove():
        sourcePath = filedialog.askdirectory()
        receivePath = filedialog.askdirectory()
        source = sourcePath
        dest = receivePath
        files = os.listdir(source) 

        now = time.time()
        for f in files:
            src = (source) +f
            dst = (dest) +f
            if os.stat(src).st_mtime > now - 1 * 86400:
                if os.path.isfile(src):
                    shutil.move(src, dst)
                    print("File move is Alright, Alright, Alright")
```

All Display with buttons

```
    def button_press():
        if one:
            x = 1
            display.configure(text=x)
        if two:
            x = 2
            display.configure(text=x)
        if three:
            x = 3
            display.configure(text=x)

    display = LabelFrame(root, bg="red", width="462", height="60")
    display.pack()

    one = Button(root, text="1", width="15", height="5",command=fromSource)
    one.pack(side="left")

    two = Button(root, text="2", width="15", height="5", command=toReceive)
    two.pack(side="left")

    three = Button(root, text="3", width="15", height="5",command=fileMove)
    three.pack(side="left")

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you tried simply adding a slash? Or use `os.path.join`?

Answer (score 11):

You should use the `os.path.join` method to join paths rather than a simple + string concatenation. This way the code will work on multiple platforms (Windows/Mac/Linux)

For example

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

current_directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
file_name = "test.txt"

file_path = os.path.join(current_directory,file_name)
print(file_path)
```